# LiPo battery protection circuits

Tags: batteries, raspberry-pi, safety, wiring, hardware

I have a Pi Zero which i need powered by a large lithium ion/polymer battery. I would like to avoid paralleling 2 or more cells because if balancing issues causes a fire, certain chestnuts will most definitely be roasted ;) (the device is on the underside of my bike). So ive been looking at a few 5000mAh+ batteries but they generally seem to come without protection circuitry (which i am unsure of how to approach that issue).

The battery im looking at:

LP7249135 - 6300mAh - 135 x 49 x 7.2mm (http://www.lipolbattery.com/li-po%20battery.html)

Currently im using an Adafruit Powerboost 500 charger to boost the voltage to 5v and charge the cell. It does provide over-charge protection and the like but i doubt that would be enough to connect a raw unprotected cell?

How would you go about adding protection circuitry and how do you know what circuitry you need for specific batteries?

Bearing in mind i have simplistic knowledge of circuitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty ready-made battery protection boards sold worldwide.

Check the battery specification for the minimum allowable voltage. Your link does not provide datasheet, so when you place your order, you should ask the seller for the datasheet before buying any battery.

Select the protection board by its overdischarge cut-off voltage. It needs to be slightly higher than battery's recommended cut-off. Talking about this kind of batteries +/-0.1V matters.

The other parameter is short circuit protection of the board. Check your Pi Zero, but I think it will consume less than 2A, so everything over that value is OK.

The third parameter is the maximum voltage (overcharge cut-off). Your charger should take care of that, but to be sure check this parameter between board specs and battery specs.